# PowerApps - screen size issues

Tags: width, publish, powerapps, dimensions, screen-size

I have created a PowerApps application with default screen width and height. But when I publish it and play the app, my application is not taking the exact dimensions (width or height) of the browser(edge). Either it's getting more zoomed in or zoomed out. How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

I have created a PowerApps application with default screen width and height. But when I publish it and play the app, my application is not taking the exact dimensions (width or height) of the browser(edge). Either it's getting more zoomed in or zoomed out. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Switch of "Scale to fit" under Settings > Display.
See No. 7 @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/set-aspect-ratio-portrait-landscape